# Why do I have twin notebook with similar content?

Tags: microsoft-onenote

[image]

How do I delete one?

Where do all those notebook stored anyway? When I click property they said it's stored in onedrive when I go to one drive directory this is what I see

[image]

However, those seems like a shortcut. The actual extension is .url and I have no idea why file explorer doesn't show that extension. And that's it.

I have no idea where the one note notes are even stored. Well, a little. There is a subfolder called

systemdocumentation_1

and it contains

[image]

2 of the folders. Side Notes Group and ToDo. There is no folder called Kerjaan. I don't know where my notes are stored?

Are these notes stored in some files? Folders? What? Are there just 2 notebook linking to the same file? Or 2 distinct notebook?

How do I get rid of one?

Update: I definitely want to just delete one of the one note.

So I right click and there is no option to delete.

It seems that I have to delete the notebook file/folder

So I try to find the folder and this is what I found

[image]

If I go to the folder all I see is a file linked to somewhere else

[image]

What should I delete to delete the notebook or say move the content of the notebook to another notebook?

Deleting the shortcut doesn't delete the notebook either. There is a folder named systemdocumentation_1 that seems to contain a bunch of text file that is similar to the notebook. Is that where the notebook is?

Comment: To show extensions in Explorer, go to *View > Options > View* and uncheck "Hide extensions for known f‌ile types".

Comment: I did that. I do not think it works for .url files